# Request.Form("ListBox1.ClientID") returning nothing

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages, request.form

```
Request.Form("ListBox1.ClientID")
```

returning nothing in `webcontentform` and `usercontrols`. But it works perfectly fine with normal webform.

All the `dropdownslist` and `Listbox` are populated by `jquery`. So the server is not able to retrieve the selected values because they really don't exist in the first place according to server, but they do exist on the client side. Then I use `Request.Form` it works perfectly fine with normal `Webform`, but it return's nothing while i use it in `webcontentpages` or `usercontrols`.

I'm really suck with this problem any ideas will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are populating items outside of the ViewState, as you said the server won't know about them due to that. You can take a look at this question for more insight:

[Client-side JavaScript ViewState Update in asp .net forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888280/client-side-javascript-viewstate-update-in-asp-net-forms)

I have used a hidden elements section in my projects with TextBoxes to store the selected values and Buttons that pass the data back to the server via a `__doPostBack();` or `$button.click();` call.

Comment: quotes are by mistake...Request.Form(ListBox1.ClientID) returns nothing.

Comment: ListBox1.SelectedValue is returning nothing because the it's been populated client side.

Comment: Where is ListBox1 and where are you trying to access it from? The MasterPage, the ContentPage, the UserControl?

Comment: Control is accessible but it's been populated by jquery and Webservice from client side.

Comment: Control is on UserControl and I'm accessing it from Usercontrol's code file .ascx

Comment: I see what you are saying, the immediate thought would be to use a hidden TextBox to store the selected value so that the server can read that.

Comment: UniqueID has does the magic, but the hidden field idea was good enough to fulfill my requirements. Thanks for sharing your idea...

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
 Request.Form(ListBox1.UniqueID)
```

Comment: If you have to populate a set of related dropdownlist(like Country,State,City) what would you prefer a cascadingdropdown or jquery???

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the values using `Request.Form`, you need to look them up by **control name**, not control ID. So first, make sure that the control ID and the control name, when rendered on the page are exactly the same if you want to be able to do `Request.Form["SomeID"]`. Secondly, it is very unlikely that the actual control id in your case is `"ListBox1.ClientID"`. I think you probably intended to do `Request.Form[ListBox1.ClientID]` instead. Thirdly, my advice is that you put a break point once the page posts back, and you add a watch to `Request.AllKeys` so that you can see exactly what are the key names that you can use to retrieve the values submitted.

Comment: All the controls are there in AllKeys, and when I tried it with UniqueID as sbhomra said it retrieved the values like magic.