# How to make ViewState null in javascript

Tags: input

I am using Viewstate to store byte array, but when i click on cancle button i want to clear viewstate from javascript on client site , How can I do this? please help me

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('ViewStateID').value=null;

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot change ViewState client-side. For one thing it's encrypted and for another, any changes will create a MAC viewstate error when the page posts back. The best that you can do is add a hidden element with the runat=server attribute and pass the value that you want to change server-side, changing it there.

[Client-side JavaScript ViewState Update in asp .net forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888280/client-side-javascript-viewstate-update-in-asp-net-forms)